# Is sleep is required before Process.StandardOutput.Read() method?

Tags: c#

I'm trying create a sub-process in C# program (cmd for example) and performing read/write with process IO streams. I'm using StandardOutput.Read() method to read process output.

When I put a Thread.Sleep() method before Read(), it gives complete output but if I remove it, it displays only single line of output.

Here is the code:

```
string sProcess = "cmd.exe";
ProcessStartInfo psiInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
psiInfo.FileName = sProcess;
psiInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
psiInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psiInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psiInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
psiInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Process pChild = new Process();
pChild.StartInfo = psiInfo;
if (pChild.Start())
{
    int ch;
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        ch = pChild.StandardOutput.Peek();
        if (ch > 0)
            Console.Write((char)pChild.StandardOutput.Read());
    } while (ch > 0);
    Console.WriteLine("exit");
    pChild.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
}
```

*Output with Sleep enabled:*

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

D:\ProcessDemo_001\bin\Release>exit
```

*Output with Sleep disabled:*

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]exit
```

I want to know why this happens?

Comment: You should use `ReadToEnd` if you just want all of the output.

Comment: I've used ReadToEnd but as I'm also sending input to the process after reading output, the ReadToEnd function blocks and I got nothing but a blank screen. Can you sort out this problem. I'ld be thankful. But thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: @Servy With `cmd.exe`, it'll never come back, since it waits for input.

Comment: That seems to be the problem.  There's no reason to be using `cmd.exe`, he should just be starting the process on the executable directly

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know why this happens?

Your loop is running faster than the output is being produced.  As soon as it gets through the output, it ends, so it never sees the second line.

Comment: So is there any other way round than just using Sleep 'cause it'll just slow down the processing...

Comment: @liquidcoder If you're executing a process that runs to completion without requiring input, then you can just wait for it to exit or read to the end of the stream.  If not, you probably need to read until you get a "prompt" character (in this case, you could read until you read in a `'>'` and then do your input...

Comment: Thanks! That I'll do. One more thing, is there any way that we can know in advance that how much data is available in Output stream of the process?

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that your Peek command is executed before pChild has output text. When that happens, ch will be 0 and the while loop quits.

Comment: Yes. I guess you knocked it right. But I've tried it with Read function also and then the do--while loop goes infinite as Read blocks as long as there is no output available from the process...

Comment: You might try yield() instead of steep() this causes the thread to stop processing and tells the OS tho do a context switch.